# Javascript: The value assigned to a global variable within a function is becoming "Undefined" outside the function

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to access the SoundCloud playlists using Javascript. so the Soundcloud `API` returns a JSON document of the entire playlist details which also has 52 tracks within it.
So I am assigning track_id[] global variable all the track IDs in it. But the value of it is valid inside the function. 
But when I try to use the value outside the function it says "undefined". So I want to use the track ID outside the function to play the track related to that track ID. so please help me do it.

```
var i = 843490127;
var track_id = [];
SC.get('/playlists/' + i).then(function(playlist) {
    playlist.tracks.forEach(function(track, index) {
        track_id[index] = track.id;
    });
    console.log("value [1]" + track_id[1]); //value valid 
});
console.log("value [1]" + track_id[1]); //undefined
```

[image: The output of the code]

Comment: The order of the console logs should give you a clue as to what happens.

Comment: the JS forEach() does not allow you to return a value outside. so the value of the track_id cannot be exported outside into a variable too. so in that cas how is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Read up on how to deal with asynchronous processes in JS